# Com criar um Request com namespace no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tentei criar uma Request com um subnamespace no Laravel 5, mas sem sucesso.

Quando eu rodo o comando `php artisan make:request Temp\OsRequest`, ao invés de criar um arquivo chamado `OsRequest` dentro de uma pasta `Temp`, é criado uma classe chamada de `TempOsRequest`.

Existe alguma maneira de criar essa classe, com o subnamespace, já dentro de uma pasta, do jeito que eu preciso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe.

Lembre-se que em muitos casos o caractere `\` representa um escape de algum caractere.

Se você adicionar duas barras (`\\`), o comando funcionará da maneira esperada, e a pasta `Temp` será criada dentro de `app\Http\Request`, e a classe `OsRequest` será criada com o subnamespace `Temp` definido.

Veja um exemplo :

```
php artisan make:request Temp\\OsRequest
```